# Moving an image through a linearlayout

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-2.2-froyo

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application.

I want to move an image from left side of the screen to the right side of the screen.

How can I do that? I've read that I have to add this image to a ListView or to a GridView to setup this animation.

**UPDATE**
I've created the following files:
**anim/translate_right**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

**anim/ship_layout_controller**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:delay="10%"
        android:animationOrder="reverse"
        android:animation="@anim/translate_right" />
```

**layout/startpage**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/appNameTextView"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40px"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PlayButton"
        android:text="@string/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40px"/>
    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/greekShip"
            android:persistentDrawingCache="animation|scrolling"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/ship_layout_controller"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/greekship"
            android:maxWidth="176px"
            android:maxHeight="87px"
            android:layout_x="-300px"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**StartActivity.java**

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startpage);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ImageView ship = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.greekShip);

        ship.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_right));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: *I've read that I have to add this image to a ListView or to a GridView to setup this animation.* you misread that. Umm... have you taken a look at the animation examples in the SDK?

Comment: Move meaning animation? If so, you can take a look at the Animation class (a simple Translate animation should do it). If you just want it aligned to the right, set the Layout Gravity to the right.

Comment: @Cristian: I'm reading Apress book Pro Android 2 and it says that.

Comment: @Zarah: Yes I want to animated a sail from left to right.

Comment: @VansFannel: OK, let me explain it in order way: you don't need neither ListView nor GridView to do this animation. So, you misread that or the book is wrong (which I think it's not feasible).

Comment: @Cristian: I've read this, 'Layout animation is almost as simple. You’ll use layout animation with the ListView and GridView, which are the two most commonly used controls in Android.' on page 224. Maybe, I've haven't understand it.

Comment: Yup... it basically means that both ListView and GridView use and can be configured to use Animations. But it does not mean to you have to use them in order to animate a View; I will try to answer to this question soon... I don't have time now. Sorry.

Comment: I have updated my question with a not working solution.

Comment: You do not have to include the ImageView in an AbsoluteLayout.  You don't have to have a layoutAnimation file, I think. I have tried and tested and used my solution below, and it works perfectly. Maybe try keeping it simple for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at the [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) class, specifically the [Tween Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween), more specifically the [Translate element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#translate-element).  Create an animation file in your project then apply this animation to your image.  For example, this animation would move an object from the center of the screen to the right side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:duration="300" 
    android:fillEnabled="true" 
    android:fillAfter="true">
</translate>
```

**EDIT:** To apply this animation to a Button, a TextView, an ImageView, etc.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
Animation exitAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.exit_animation);
imageView.startAnimation(exitAnimation);
```

Comment: I've read that tween animation is for elements inside of a view not to move the entire view.

Comment: Have you tried it, at least? An image _IS_ a view, after all.

Comment: I want to move an ImageView, not the image inside the imageView.

Comment: Tweened Animations Tweened animations are applied to Views, letting you define a series
of changes in position, size, rotation, and opacity that animate the View contents.

Comment: EXACTLY. That is what you want, right? Again, have you tried if this works?

Comment: No, I want to move the entire ImageView.

Comment: So apply the Animation to the ImageView. Check out my edit in my answer.  If that is still not what you want, then I am totally confused.

Comment: Thanks friend, I implemented your code . Its working. And insted of ImageView I used LinearLayout, it looks cool....

Comment: `R.anim` is causing me problems, it's showing me an error and says "anim" cannot be resolved

Comment: @SSHThis: Did you try doing a Project > Clean? Check that you are using the correct file name for the R.anim reference.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use **Translate Animation**. For example, this animation would move an image from Left side of the screen to the right side of the screen.

The AnimationActivity is

```
    listener = new AnimationListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        @Override 
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            System.out.println("End Animation!");
            //load_animations();
        }
    };

     }
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v==button)
    {
        moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, 200, 0, 0);
        moveLefttoRight.setDuration(1000);
        moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);
        my_image.startAnimation(moveLefttoRight);
    }
    }

  }
```

xml code is

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/diceid"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/dice"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and **anim** file is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <rotate
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromDegrees="0"
   android:toDegrees="360"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"
   android:duration="2000"
   android:repeatMode="reverse"
   android:repeatCount="infinite"
   android:startOffset="0"
  />
```

may be this is the answer what you are searching.

Comment: This is awesome! How about instead of rotate I wanted to translate to it's location within the layout and fade in at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I would check your source again. Maybe it's out of context. But the easiest way to do this is to use a Translate animation that originates from the Image's starting place and translates it to the other side of the screen. After that is done I usually register an animation callback so that I can update the true position of the image after the animation is over. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or is it the [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) that you are looking for?